# Stop deletes via EditForm.aspx using SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog going to List view page

Tags: 2010, javascript, client-object-model

If you use [SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff410058.aspx) to show a Lists standard EditForm.aspx the callback (dialogReturnCallback) is hit for cancels and edits but not deletes which are instead redirected to the list view (AllItems.apx) via a 302.

How can I stop deletes via EditForm.aspx getting 302 redirected?

Example javascript (itemId is ID of record you're editing)

```
var options = {};
options.url = "/YOUR_SITE/Lists/YOUR_LIST/EditForm.aspx";
// If we don't append ?ID=X onto end of url then won't have context of edited record
// so won't enabled ribbon Edit button and a save will throw 500 server error    
options.url = options.url + "?ID=" + itemId;

options.dialogReturnValueCallback =
           function (dialogResult, returnValue) {
                  // Cancels and Saves will get here, Deletes will not,
                  // page redirected to standard list view (AllItems.aspx)
                  // via a 302 redirect.
                  console.log("dialogResult=" + dialogResult +
                              " returnValue=" + returnValue);
              }
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid it is a standard behavior and there is no setting out there to change this.

But I can propose a workaround...

When the ribbon **Delete** button is pressed on a list form, SharePoint requests user confirmation, and then performs postback. Thus, redirection happens server-side and nothing could be changed here.

However, nothing prevents you from deleting the item client-side (using client object model), and then you can just close the dialog using either [SP.UI.ModalDialog.commandModalDialogClose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff409682.aspx) method or window.frameElement.commitPopup shortcut.

The code will look something like this:

```
if (!confirm("Are you sure want to delete this item?")) return;
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
var item = list.getItemById(parseInt(GetUrlKeyValue("ID")));
item.recycle();
if (GetUrlKeyValue("IsDlg") != "1")
  context.load(list);
context.executeQueryAsync(
    function()
    {
        if (GetUrlKeyValue("IsDlg") == "1")
        {
            window.frameElement.commitPopup("item deleted");
        }
        else
        {
            document.location.href=list.get_defaultViewUrl();
        }
    },
    function(sender,args) {alert('Error! ' + args.get_message());});
```

To make this code work, of course you will need to replace standard **Delete** button with your own custom one, which will look alike, but will act differently.

You will need to perform this operation for all list forms. Initial button definitions can be grabbed from the `14\TEMPLATE\GLOBAL\XML\CMDUI.XML` file.

For example, standard definition of Delete button on Display form is presented below:

```
<Button
   Id="Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Manage.DeleteItem"
   Sequence="50"
   Command="Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Manage.DeleteItem"
   Image16by16="/_layouts/$Resources:core,Language;/images/formatmap16x16.png" Image16by16Top="-112" Image16by16Left="-224"
   Image32by32="/_layouts/$Resources:core,Language;/images/formatmap32x32.png" Image32by32Top="-128" Image32by32Left="-128"
   LabelText="$Resources:core,cui_ButDeleteItem;"
   ToolTipTitle="$Resources:core,cui_ButDeleteItem;"
   ToolTipDescription="$Resources:core,cui_STT_ButListFormDeleteItem;"
   TemplateAlias="o2"/>
```

Obviously, you need to change *Id* and *Command* attributes here, providing your own identifiers.

Then, wrap this code into CommandUIDefinition element, setting Location attribute to original ID value:

```
<CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Manage.DeleteItem">
    <Button
       Id="Ribbon.Ryan.DeleteItem"
       Sequence="50"
       Command="Ribbon.Ryan.DeleteItem"
       ...
    />
</CommandUIDefinition>
```

Repeat the trick for Edit form, and then wrap these CommandUIDefinition elements into proper CustomAction code, and of course do not forget to provide command handler for the "Ribbon.Ryan.DeleteItem" command and put the code presented above there :)

For details of how ribbon customizations are performed, and for examples of custom action code, you can examine the following MSDN how-to:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms473643.aspx

(*Location* attribute of the *CustomAction* element should be set to "CommandUI.Ribbon", to apply the customization to all list forms).

Comment: Outstanding again, cheers. Unfortunately isn't going to work for this project (http://sprello.codeplex.com/) as can't be modifying existing lists for the sake of my web part.

Comment: you can deploy this customization for all lists, and then pass a parameter and by existance of this parameter you can determine if you need to use custom code or just call the original postback.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to modify OOTB JS behavior without actually editting the SHarePoint JS files the [jquery.aop plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-aop/). It allows for adding before and after (and a few more) "aspects" (function calls) to another function, without actually having to rewrite that other function.